# Having trouble with Between Dates

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery to extract some data here but whenever I try to add Between dates I won't receive the information in the correct way.

Any ideas why this is not bringing me the values withing the range?

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT FECHA,
  product_trademark,
  VENTAS,
  ORDENES,
  USUARIOS,
  main_grouped_store
FROM
DB
WHERE
  product_trademark LIKE '%Kero-Coco%'
  OR product_trademark LIKE '%kero-coco%'
  AND COUNTRY = 'BR'
  AND FECHA BETWEEN '201908' AND '201910'
ORDER BY
  VENTAS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that FECHA field is a STRING with YYYYMM pattern - Most likely your problem is in mixing OR and AND - so try below

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  FECHA, 
  product_trademark, 
  VENTAS, 
  ORDENES, 
  USUARIOS, 
  main_grouped_store 
FROM DB 
WHERE (product_trademark LIKE '%Kero-Coco%' 
OR product_trademark LIKE '%kero-coco%') 
AND COUNTRY = 'BR' 
AND FECHA BETWEEN '201908' AND '201910' 
ORDER BY VENTAS
```

as an option - you can collapse two OR'ed conditions into one like in below example

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  FECHA, 
  product_trademark, 
  VENTAS, 
  ORDENES, 
  USUARIOS, 
  main_grouped_store 
FROM DB 
WHERE LOWER(product_trademark) LIKE '%kero-coco%' 
AND COUNTRY = 'BR' 
AND FECHA BETWEEN '201908' AND '201910' 
ORDER BY VENTAS
```

Comment: Hey buddy, it worked!!

So basically you added the ( ) between the first Where statement, right?

Comment: right! those two conditions for product_trademark should be enclosed in brackets